# How do I receive incoming serialPort data in every 2 seconds?

Tags: c#, timer, serial-port, logic

So right now I have a button that upon clicking it shall open a serial port for communication. But the problem is the data that I received from my serial port comes in every milliseconds that it fills up my textbox rapidly.

How do I control it in such that I shall use `serialPortN.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);` to receive data for every 2 seconds or so?

This is what I have for my button:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cboComPort.SelectedIndex == -1)    //if no Com Port is selected
        {   //To show error message
            MessageBox.Show("You must select the port first!");

        }
        else
        {
            // If Serial Port is already open, close it first
            if (serialPortN.IsOpen)
                serialPortN.Close();
            try
            {
                // comport parameters
                serialPortN.PortName = cboComPort.Text;
                serialPortN.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPortN.Parity = Parity.None;
                serialPortN.DataBits = 8;
                serialPortN.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                serialPortN.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                serialPortN.ReadTimeout = 500;

                // Open Serial port for communications
                serialPortN.Open();
                txtPortStatus.Text = "OPEN";

                btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
                btnConnect.Enabled = false;

                // to receive incoming data received by the serial port,
                serialPortN.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the data received into a collection/queue, and start a timer which every 2 seconds takes the data you want from the queue and put it in your textbox.

Comment: Post your datareceived method to check a solution based on your code, but @Daniel is the fast way.

Comment: Increase the ReceivedBytesThreshold, so that the DataReceived event is not fired so often.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes the data you want"?  I'm monitoring temperatures from a sensor, so all data received regardless of how fast it is, is relevant.  I just want to read the the temperature in every 2 seconds or so

Comment: I mean you said you can't write the data to the textbox as it comes as the rate of events is too fast. I'm suggesting you add that data to a queue, and every 2 seconds either take the latest data, aggregate in some way, do what ever you need. I can't be more specific as I don't know what you do with the data.

Comment: Ah, that make sense.  Any example I could refer to using your method?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

1. Create a Timer and somewhere to store your data

   ```
   private System.Windows.Forms.Timer portTimer;
   private StringBuilder receievedData = new StringBuilder();
   private object receivedDataLock = new object();
   ```
2. Setup and start your timer (when you open the port perhaps)

   ```
   portTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   portTimer.Interval = 2000;
   portTimer.Tick += portTimer_Tick;
   portTimer.Start();
   ```
3. In your data received handler for the port, save the data

   ```
   private void serialPortN_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
       byte [] buffer = new byte[serialPortN.BytesToRead];
       int numRead = serialPortN.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);            
       // Ensure we arent trying to modify string builder from 2 different threads simultaneously
       lock(receivedDataLock){
           // Assuming the data is in ASCII text format if you are displaying to text box            
           receievedData.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
       }
   }
   ```
4. Do something with the data in your timer handler:

   ```
   void portTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (receievedData.Length > 0)
       {
           lock (receivedDataLock)
           {
               String data = receievedData.ToString();
               // Do something with your string, then empty the StringBuilder
               receievedData = new StringBuilder();
           }
       }
   }
   ```